# loop through empty string

Tags: linux, loops, for-loop, ksh

Recently I found a part of code which confuses me:

```
typeset _Var=''

for _Var
do
   ... a command
done
```

can anyone explain how this loops through an empty list of values is working?

thanks a lot for any post.

Comment: Actually, it does not !!

Comment: The empty string in `typeset _Var=''` is a red herring.  The for keyword will provide _Var with other values, explicit with the **in** keyword, or implicit with out.  See below.

Comment: That’s because `for x` + newline(!) + `do` is equivalent to POSIX shell `for x in "$@"; do`. Note that you **cannot** use `for x; do` because some shells misparse that. Source: GNU autoconf texinfo manual, section about portable shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construct

```
for var
do
    echo something
done
```

without the `in` keyword will default to the list of positional parameters, e.g., `$1`, `$2`, etc.

So your script will execute the loop body once for each separate 
argument on the command line.

The snippet above invoked as `ksh testscript a b c` will output:

```
something
something
something
```